# Solve integer equation $2^m.m^2=9n^2-12n+19$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Problem: Find $m,n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ satisfies: $2^m.m^2=9n^2-12n+19$.

This is my attempt:
We have $9n^2-12n+19\equiv 1 \pmod 3$, so: $2^{m}m^2\equiv 1 \pmod 3\tag{1}$

In addition, we have: $$m^2\equiv 0\text{ or }1 \pmod 3 $$

So $(1)\implies m\equiv \pm 1\pmod 3$.

Suppose that: $m=3k+1(k\in \mathbb{N})$.

We have: $$2^{m}m^2=2^{3k+1}(3k+1)^2=8^{k}(3k+1)^22\equiv 2^{k+1}(3k+1)^{2}\pmod 3\\ \implies k\equiv 1\pmod 2$$
I can only come here!!

Comment: One solution would be m = 2 and n = 1, just by brute force.

Comment: So, it means: If $m=2$. The equation has solution, that is $(m,n)=(2,1)$.

Comment: If $m>2$. The equation has no solution ?

Comment: What's the source of this problem? That might help in formulating attempts to solve it using knowledge you're expected to have available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, let's complete the square on the RHS and write it as $(3n-2)^2+15$.  Next, suppose $m$ is odd.  Then $2^mm^2$ will be $\equiv 2\pmod 4$ (can you see why?) but the RHS — as a sum of a square and a number $\equiv 3\pmod 4$ — will be congruent to either $3$ or $0$, so they can't be equivalent.
Now, suppose $m$ is even; then $m=2r$, say, and so the LHS $m^22^m = (2r)^22^{2r} = \left(r2^{r+1}\right)^2$.  This means we can write $a^2=b^2+15$, where $a=r2^{r+1}$ and $b=3n-2$.  This can be written perhaps more suggestively as $a^2-b^2=15$; can you take it from there?

Comment: Your answer says "Next, suppose $m$ is odd.  Then $2^mm^2$ will be $\equiv 2\pmod 4$ (can you see why?)". If $m = 1$, this is true. However, if $m \ge 3$, then $2^m m^2 = 4(2^{m-2}) m^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, i.e., it's **not** $\equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Glah - you're 100% right there.  Let me see if that chunk of things can be salvaged.

Comment: Note that [Mike](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/544150/mike) has posted an answer giving a very simple proof that $m$ being odd doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The case left open by the above answer is for $m$ odd. If $m$ is odd, then $m^2\times 2^m = 2A^2$ for some integer $A$; namely $A = m\times 2^{\frac{m-1}{2}}$. Thus we are left with the equation

$$2A^2 = (3n-2)^2+15$$

Note that the LHS of the equation is either 2 or 0 mod 3, whereas the RHS is always 1.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.